# In a contingency table, what does it mean to say a variable is categorical?

Tags: statistics

In a contingency table, what does it mean to say a variable is categorical?

This must be a simple question, but I find it a bit confusing.

To clarify further the question, how does it differ from say, a numerical variable?

Comment: [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable)

Comment: It's sometimes difficult to filter out what is accurate and what is not on wikipedia, so I tend to avoid it when I'm already confused about a topic.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Elodie: I made an effort to write a good, thorough answer. I am not asking neither for upvotes nor for your accepting my answer, but I would appreciate some feedback from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A(n) EDIT Nominal categorical variable is one in which the values belong to pre-asigned , disjoint categories/groups ,say countries, blood-types, or any other well-defined grouping , meaning every value will fall into exactly one of the categories.These are mostly either Nominal, Ordinal and Likert . In the case of nominal variables, the difference with numerical variables is that there is no natural associated magnitude nor ordering to the categories; unlike numbers, categories cannot be naturally said to be larger than each other ( there is no natural ordering of the categories) , or some are positive, negative. For example, with the grouping by handedness, a person may be right-handed, left-handed or ambidextrous, which are mutually exclusive and comprise every value ( every person performing a certain task). No one category is "larger" than another by any naturally given measure. As pointed out, there are other types of categorical variables for which *some* comparisons with numbers that do not hold within the Nominal types can be made, such as ordinal or Likert-scaled . Ordinal ones denote an ordering , exm. "First, Second, Third, etc. " , while Likert scales assign a number to denote the extent or degree of some condition or state of things. EDIT 2, As pointed out by Bruce , there is more to it, maybe the common difference is the lack of relative  scaling , even for ordinal variables or Likert scales ; in an ordinal variable , there is no scale by which the relation of the n-th ordered category to the (n-1)st is the same as the scale relation between the (n-1)st and the (n-2_nd ). Same goes for Likert -scaled categories. There is no natural scale by which the 3rd ordered object is larger than the 2nd, the 2nd to the first. etc. Same for Likert scales.

Comment: You correctly describe _nominal_ categories. By contrast, _ordinal_ categories do have a natural order. Perhaps the most common is for survey results 'Strongly opposed', Somewhat opposed' , 'Neutral', 'Somewhat favor', and 'Strongly favor' with respect to a candidate or ballot proposition.

Comment: @BruceET: Good point. I added what I think is the essential difference: the lack of a natural scale, even for ordinal or Likert -categorical variables.

Comment: @BruceET: Is what I wrote correct?

Comment: Opinions differ, but what you added seems OK. Psychologists and sociologists sometimes attribute structure to Likert scales that many statisticians find fanciful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Elodie: No problem, glad it helped.